# understanding http request format

Tags: http-headers

Following are 3 http header request format i have extracted from google chrome browser. Those 3 request format are for html, xml and json. How the server will know which one is html, xml or json and respond accordingly?

```
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Connection:keep-alive
    Cookie:_depot_session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlZjhlMzg2MjM3YWJlYzg2NzgyZTk0MmM2MzQzOTI1YWVJIgxjYXJ0X2lkBjsARmksSSIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4GOwBGSSIxMk9PaHhzVVpqNkJ2VnYxQnZwL3E5UWlZbFFjKzF3Mm9CUEhtT2c2TWd0VT0GOwBGSSIMdXNlcl9pZAY7AEZpDA%3D%3D--e672d35300801a62050521d5d2ed381f263126a7
    Host:localhost:3000
    Referer:http://localhost:3000/en/products
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36





   Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:69
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cookie:_depot_session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlZjhlMzg2MjM3YWJlYzg2NzgyZTk0MmM2MzQzOTI1YWVJIgxjYXJ0X2lkBjsARmksSSIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4GOwBGSSIxMk9PaHhzVVpqNkJ2VnYxQnZwL3E5UWlZbFFjKzF3Mm9CUEhtT2c2TWd0VT0GOwBGSSIMdXNlcl9pZAY7AEZpDA%3D%3D--e672d35300801a62050521d5d2ed381f263126a7
    Host:localhost:3000
    Origin:http://localhost:3000
    Referer:http://localhost:3000/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36






    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:69
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cookie:_depot_session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlZjhlMzg2MjM3YWJlYzg2NzgyZTk0MmM2MzQzOTI1YWVJIgxjYXJ0X2lkBjsARmksSSIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4GOwBGSSIxMk9PaHhzVVpqNkJ2VnYxQnZwL3E5UWlZbFFjKzF3Mm9CUEhtT2c2TWd0VT0GOwBGSSIMdXNlcl9pZAY7AEZpDA%3D%3D--e672d35300801a62050521d5d2ed381f263126a7
    Host:localhost:3000
    Origin:http://localhost:3000
    Referer:http://localhost:3000/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I think browser send the request type depending on your specified parameter

Comment: There's no request type in HTTP. Look at your headers, they all have the same `Accept:` header.

Answer (score 1):

You have a method called [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) which will take care of the requests

```
  def index
    @people = Person.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.xml { render :xml => @people.to_xml }
      format.json {render :json => @people.to_json}
    end
  end
```

The above method in controller will respond according to the request format