# How server respond for html, ajax, xml and json for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I send request in html, ajax, xml and json. For xml and json I do it by writing :format => 'json/xml', for ajax we write :remote => true.

But how server know that it has to respond with ajax, xml or json? 
One thing I noticed when I send json or xml request it show in the url like below

```
http://localhost:3000/en/line_items.json
```

Though Im not sure, this is how server know if he has to give json response. But for html and ajax something like this is don't add in the url. So how server know whether it is ajax or html request?

Comment: Answer is in Request Headers

Comment: I checked request headers and in google chrome every request is same.
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824100/understanding-http-request-format' request headers are given here

Comment: Read here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html Also there is a method `xml_http_request?` jQuery has `contentType` option http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Request headers are governed by [mime-types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), which basically determine which type of content / request is being sent

Rails has an in-built handler to manage different responses. As per @hawk's URL on [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html), you can see this middleware essentially catches the type of request sent from the browser

---

**Respond_To**

The real answer to your question is about the [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) block:

```
#apps/controller/your_controller.rb
def new
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { # do stuff here }
        format.js { # do stuff here }
        format.json { # do stuff here }
    end
end
```

This will allow you to send various responses depending on the mime-type sent in the request :)